# When i create the controller with view,using EF core DB Context(Application DB Context) is not getting in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created a web application using ap.net core 3.1 (Individual User Account). And when I am creating an MVC Controller with view, using EF it is not working as it was. The select box of "Data context class" is empty. But there should have the ApplicationBBContext, as I used the individual user accounts. Even when I am creating a view selecting the action of the controller the view is not creating in the view folder it is creating in the controller folder.

[image]

[image: d]

Comment: Was it ever working on this solution, or since it's brand new this is immediately the case?

Comment: You can try to execute `update-database` command in Package Manager Console and then re-create it again.